# LastPass on Safari not autofilling if auto fill is unchecked

Tags: safari, password

I'm trying to migrate from Chrome to Safari and I'm having trouble with the [LastPass extension](https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.lastpass.lpsafariextension-N24REP3BMN).

What is annoying me is Safari always asking me to save my passwords in its own password storage mechanism, which I don't want to use. As far as I know, if I don't want to receive these alerts asking to save passwords I have to uncheck the option to auto fill user and password in Safari's Preferences>Autofill. But if I do that, the auto fill feature from LastPass stops working...

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted Lastpass's support and they told me this is a known issue and will be fixed in the version 4.17...

Answer (score 5):

This is an ongoing issue.

1. Open Preferences in Safari and select the Extensions tab
2. Select LastPass in the left-hand column.
3. Click "Uninstall" and confirm it
4. Go to https://lastpass.com/misc_download2.php?tab=mac#maclpmacosx
5. Scroll down to "LastPass for Safari" and click on "Download".
6. Go to your downloads folder and double-click on `lastpass.safariextz`.
7. Safari Extensions Preferences should open with a dialog box stating "Would you like to install ..."
8. Click on "Install from Developer" in the dialog box.
9. A dialog box will appear stating "Are you sure you want to install the extension LastPass..." and click on "Trust" in that dialog box.
10. LastPass will now show in the left-hand column of the Extensions Preferences and it will show that the version is 4.9.0.37.
11. A new Safari tab or window will open and at the bottom will be a "Log In" link. Click on it. This may not leave you logged in, but at this point you should be able to log in as you normally would.
12. You can then go to LastPass Preferences and set the preferences to your own liking.

Comment: So a new version introduced this issue? I'm trying now :)

Comment: It seems we cannot install this older version anymore with the latest safari update :(